# Having trouble with tx-proxy

Tags: monerod, tor

I created a test transaction to test broadcasting monero tx over Tor, from a computer running a full node.

On that computer, I started monerod with the following options:

./monerod --tx-proxy tor,127.0.0.1:9050 --add-peer xmrtolujkxnlinre.onion:18081

Note that I have tor running as a background service, so the tx-proxy should work, and that is the known onion node for xmr.to.

The computer is behind a firewall and is configured to allow no incoming connections, but presumably it should be able to use this known peer to send a transaction, right?

However, the tx did not send. The wallet claims the tx is still pending in the tx pool, with no confirmations.

So, first question: Have I done something incorrect here?

Second question: If I were to restart ./monerod without the tx-proxy option, would it finally send out the pooled tx, or do I effectively need to start over?

Answer (score 2):

> `--add-peer xmrtolujkxnlinre.onion:18081`... that is the known onion node for xmr.to

Here is your misunderstanding: `--add-peer` is for adding *peer* nodes, nodes that will talk to each other on the Monero P2P network. It is **not** for using another nodes JSON RPC interface (which is all that xmrtolujkxnlinre.onion is offering up [[ref](https://community.xmr.to/nodes.html)]).

Thus if you want a full node to relay transactions to other nodes over Tor/i2p, you need to add a peer node that is listening for P2P traffic over an anonymity network via their usage of `--anonymous-inbound ...`.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Is there a list somewhere of nodes that listen for p2p traffic over an anonymity network? I'm not clear on how such nodes can discover one another. I also tried moneroworld's zdhkwneu7lfaum2p.onion:18099 without success, so maybe that has the same issue (or maybe my node didn't rebroadcast the tx after I restarted the daemon with the moneroworld noded added as a peer)?

Comment: The loose plan is for some trusted seed nodes first, to help the less technical users. Of course you can run a node on an anonymous network yourself in the meantime.

Comment: That's essentially what I'm trying to accomplish, unless you mean something different by "anonymous node" than the intuitive meaning. My understanding is that the whole point of anonymity networks is to make my node anonymous to others in the sense that when one broadcast txs, the ip address of my node is unclear. Is there some other way to achieve this other than --tx-proxy to a known tor or i2p node? Is there some other useful definition of anonymity as a monero node?

Comment: I was specific with my words in the answer: "anonymity network". As in, hide your source and destination IP addresses and encrypt traffic.There are of course a plethora of things that can be done which work to differing degrees. Nothing is perfect. At the lower end, just running your own full node for many will be sufficient, as a wallet sending a tx to your own node for relaying makes it pretty difficult for an adversary to determine the original broadcast node.

Comment: You also need to understand that a wallet talks to a node via the JSON RPC interface, thus trivial to perform that over an anonymous network - and in fact the command-line wallet even has [options](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/master/ANONYMITY_NETWORKS.md#wallet-rpc) to simplify further. Nodes *relay* txs to other nodes, and they do this over the Monero p2p network.

Comment: It sounds like sending p2p traffic exclusively over anonymity network isn't practical yet, since there are no seeds and no way for nodes to discover one another. So if you want to connect your wallet to your own full node, you must operate that full node in the clear, or it won't be able to relay your tx. Is that correct?

Comment: I'm aware you can connect to a remote node over Tor, but then you lose the benefits of having your own local copy of the blockchain. So my goal is to have my wallet using a local node, communicating with other nodes only over Tor or i2p.

Comment: "It sounds like sending p2p traffic exclusively over anonymity network isn't practical yet,.."< "exclusively" of course not, that would require all participants to be on the/an anonymous network.

Comment: "So if you want to connect your wallet to your own full node, you must operate that full node in the clear, or it won't be able to relay your tx. Is that correct?"<- No it is not correct. It can be configured to relay to node(s) on an anonymous net, using the very parameters you misunderstood in your original question. It is a nuanced topic that is really not suited to SE comments! Perhaps you should collate your thoughts into a new question so I can answer them more fully.