# In monerod, is --add-peer necessary when using --tx-proxy to discover anonymous peers?

Tags: monerod, monerod-commands, i2p, tor

From https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/master/docs/ANONYMITY_NETWORKS.md it seems you don't *have* to specify `--add-peer`:

> If desired, peers can be manually specified:
>
> --add-exclusive-node rveahdfho7wo4b2m.onion:28083
> --add-peer rveahdfho7wo4b2m.onion:28083

Notice it says, ***if desired,*** not *required*.  But from @jtgrassie's answer at [How do you setup a node to communicate with other nodes only over an anonymous network?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/12040/how-do-you-setup-a-node-to-communicate-with-other-nodes-only-over-an-anonymous-n/12042#12042):

> If you add one or more nodes that are on anonymous networks, yes, they will share their peerlists of other anonymous nodes they have connected to.

This makes me think that `--add-peer` might be necessary to discover *anonymous* peers.  However, this answer was from March of 2020, so a lot might have changed from then.

Do clearnet peers also provide anonymous peer addresses to other clearnet peers?

***Edit:*** At the time of this writing, `--add-peer` or `--add-exclusive-node` is no longer necessary to obtain tor peer seeds in mainnet since there are some default peers added in the source (see https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/f9d789d68ccca9a9b4aba483b7faa03a062c50c3/src/p2p/net_node.inl#L856-L859).  For stagenet seed peers, add peers manually by finding them here https://monero.fail/?nettype=stagenet&onion=true )

Comment: I am fairly certain that it is not needed currently, as [this particular pull request](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/pull/6990) added seed nodes for both i2p and tor. Evidently, if you have a specific node that you would like to connect to, the flag can still be useful.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't seem like tor/i2p seed nodes are provided.  I tested it on stagenet and couldn't get a transaction to be relayed, it just sat in the pool.  Also if you look at that pull request, lines 742-756 or so, you'll see this:
`case epee::net_utils::zone::tor:`
`return {};`
Which looks like there are no default seed nodes except for clearnet (via DNS)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This makes me think that --add-peer might be necessary...

`--add-peer` is *not* required. But you have to use either `--add-peer` or `--add-exclusive-node` with an anonymity network if you want to send transactions over that network.

As you're quoting from my answer, I'll quote this (with emphasis) from the same:

> > Node to node communication, i.e. P2P traffic: for this you can use --tx-proxy ... and **--add-peer ... / --add-exclusive-node** ... with a node **on an anonymity network** to broadcast transactions only over the anonymity network.

"--add-peer ... / --add-exclusive-node ..." the forward slash means you should read as "--add-peer ... **and / or** --add-exclusive-node ...".

(the exclusive variant ensures transactions are only sent via that node).

> Do clearnet peers also provide anonymous peer addresses to other clearnet peers?

No. Peers are in *zones* (i.e. tor, i2p or clearnet). If you're connected to a peer in a *zone*, you'll get peers for *that zone*.

Comment: Thanks @jtgrassie, I appreciate the clarity but I'm still a bit confused.  I haven't added any peers via `--add-peer` or `--add-exlusive-node` and if I run `print_pl white`, I see several peers ending with a `.onion` address. I tried adding one of those peers via `--add-peer`, but when I try to have my node relay my own transfers, I get `W Unable to send transaction(s) to tor - no available outbound connections`. If clearnet peers don't provide anonymous peer addresses, what are those ".onion" peers in the peerlist? Is there somewhere I can find tor seed peers for stagenet?

Comment: Are you actually connected to the tor network?

Comment: I am connected via my tor process. I’m not sure how to check if the monerod process is using tor successfully. How else would those peers listed with a “.onion” address get into the peer list? I do have a --txproxy line pointing to my tor proxy and curl over the socks5 tor proxy is working correctly.

Comment: "--txproxy" should be `--tx-proxy`. Additionally, just because you've found a tor onion in the peer-list, does not mean that node is online right now; try another. You have to connect to a peer that has used `--anonymous-inbound` and is currently online.

Comment: sorry, I am indeed using `--tx-proxy` and not `--txproxy` (typo in my comment) .  Also, if I only show peers via `print_pl white` doesn't that only show peers that are online right now?  Even if they weren't online, how did they get there if I never added any peers directly via `--add-peer` ?

Comment: 1) "doesn't that only show peers that are online right now?" no, white peers are peers you performed a handshake with at some point, it doesn't mean they are *currently* online or that you're currently *connected* to them. 2) "how did they get there" there are now tor *seed* nodes [coded](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/f9d789d68ccca9a9b4aba483b7faa03a062c50c3/src/p2p/net_node.inl#L856-L859) into monero..

Comment: I see, thanks @jtgrassie.  That's great that the seed nodes are coded directly into Monero!  Doesn't that mean that you don't have to use either `--add-peer` or `--add-exclusive-node` anymore with an anonymity network? It looks like from that code snippet you linked this is only true for mainnet, is that right?  If so, do you know where I might be able to find stagenet onion peers?  Also, I thought "white" peers are "online and reachable" (from: https://monerodocs.org/interacting/monerod-reference/#commands)

Comment: 1) The [unofficial doc](https://monerodocs.org/interacting/monerod-reference/#commands) you reference is incorrect. Again, white peers are peers you performed a handshake with *at some point*, this *doesn't* mean they are *currently* online or that you're currently connected to them. 2) As for stagenet onion peers, see https://monero.fail/?nettype=stagenet&onion=true

Comment: Ok thanks again.  It looks like that documentation should be changed on monerodocs.org then.  Who can I contact to help/notify?

Comment: No idea who maintains that site (though there is contact info on the front page), but it's *wrong* about white *and* grey peers (and a load of other things). E.g. a grey peer isn't necessarily "offline" (as it states), you just haven't tried connecting to it yet; nor are they from "past sessions"!

Comment: Fixed in https://github.com/MAGICGrants/getmonero.dev/commit/53cd19283db200e4be60be02d6e64c462ac071a7

https://getmonero.dev/docs/interacting/monerod-reference.html#p2p-network-1